# Find values in indexed columns of pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe like following

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2,4,5,6], 'col2': [3, 4,5,6,7], 'col3': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz','biz', 'boo'] }    

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d) 
df.head()

   col1  col2 col3
0     1     3  foo
1     2     4  bar
2     4     5  baz
3     5     6  biz
4     6     7  boo
```

Now, I want to index all the columns..
`indexed_df = df.set_index(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])`

How do I search for a particular value in this indexed df

Like if i want to search for baz in df
I will do

```
df[df.col3 == 'baz']
```

How do I do the same thing with indexed_df

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways:

**Option 1**: [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)

```
indexed_df.query('col3=="baz"')
```

**Option 2**: [`xs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html)

```
indexed_df.xs('baz', level='col3', drop_level=False)
```

**Option 3**: [`get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
indexed_df.loc[indexed_df.index.get_level_values('col3')=='baz']
```

---

Let's assume that there is some data

```
indexed_df = df.set_index(['col1', 'col2', 'col3']).assign(value=1)
```

Any of the above would give:

```
                value
col1 col2 col3       
4    5    baz       1
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.. One last question. what if one of the index columns is list
Say: col4 has one row with list values [1,2,3,4]
And I want to search for 4 in col4?

Comment: That sounds like a question of its own. There are also few options, `explode` the series and `groupby().max()` seems to be viable. But I can't tell exactly without a data :-). And it won't fit in a comment anyway.

Comment: asked a follow up here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66594552/find-values-in-indexed-columns-of-pandas-which-is-a-list thanks for the help