# find values in indexed columns of pandas which is a list

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe like following

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2,4,5,6], 'col2': [3, 4,5,6,7], 'col3': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz','biz', 'boo'],
    'col4': [['foo', 'bar'], ['baz'], ['foo'], ['biz'], ['baz', 'foo']]
}    

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d) 
df.head()

   col1  col2 col3        col4
0     1     3  foo  [foo, bar]
1     2     4  bar       [baz]
2     4     5  baz       [foo]
3     5     6  biz       [biz]
4     6     7  boo  [baz, foo]
```

Lets say I index column 4

```
indexed_df = df.set_index('col4')  
 indexed_df                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[42]: 
            col1  col2 col3
col4                       
[foo, bar]     1     3  foo
[baz]          2     4  bar
[foo]          4     5  baz
[biz]          5     6  biz
[baz, foo]     6     7  boo
```

How do i set a value in index.
Say.. search for "baz" in col4?
Thanks

Comment: jezrael's answer is excellent as always. I just feel it's super weird to have `list` as index: you can't slice by `loc` any more, plus, you may lose all of the vectorization stuff.

Comment: I'm agree with @QuangHoang. Why don't you use a `MultiIndex`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html) with `in` statement:

```
df1 = indexed_df[indexed_df.index.map(lambda x: 'baz' in x)]
print (df1)
            col1  col2 col3
col4                       
[baz]          2     4  bar
[baz, foo]     6     7  boo
```

Alternative with list comprehension:

```
df1 = indexed_df[['baz' in x for x in indexed_df.index]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us just try `explode`

```
out = indexed_df[pd.Series(indexed_df.index).explode().isin(['baz']).any(level=0).values]
Out[241]: 
            col1  col2 col3
col4                       
[baz]          2     4  bar
[baz, foo]     6     7  boo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of using `MultiIndex` rather than a list as index:

```
>>> df.set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(d["col4"]))
         col1  col2 col3        col4
foo bar     1     3  foo  [foo, bar]
baz NaN     2     4  bar       [baz]
foo NaN     4     5  baz       [foo]
biz NaN     5     6  biz       [biz]
baz foo     6     7  boo  [baz, foo]
```

Comment: How do we get rows with "baz" in the MultiIndex?

Comment: `df.loc["baz"]`

Comment: `.loc` seems to only look at the first col of the MultiIndex? e.g., `df.loc['foo']` only picks up rows 0 and 2 but not 4.

Comment: `pd.concat([df.xs("foo", level=0), df.xs("foo", level=1)])`

Comment: Take a look at [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index)